# Как очистить корзину при помощи Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Мне нужно очистить корзину в Windows используя Python
Как я могу это реализовать?
Когда я искал в инете ч нашел только один способ используя модуль winshell , но я даже его импортировать не могу ( ошибка на скриншоте)
Есть какие нибудь альтернативы?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fvKB.jpg]

Код:

```
import winshell
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
  import winshell
ImportError: No module named 'win32con'
```

Comment: pip, а не pip3 мог установить версию для второго питона, но я не уверен, не знаю, как это в виндовс устроено

Comment: Также, текст нужно в виде текста в вопросе приводить, а не скриншотов

Comment: Ошибка на скриншоте не совпадает с ошибкой в приведенном тексте. Советую внимательнее читать тексты на экране. PS. А заголовок вопроса не соответствует содержимому.

Answer (score 2):

[пример](https://programtalk.com/vs2/python/13102/winshell/winshell.py/):

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon   # pip install pywin32

def empty(confirm=True, show_progress=True, sound=True):
    flags = 0
    if not confirm:
        flags |= shellcon.SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION
    if not show_progress:
        flags |= shellcon.SHERB_NOPROGRESSUI
    if not sound:
        flags |= shellcon.SHERB_NOSOUND
    shell.SHEmptyRecycleBin(None, None, flags)
```